# Successive matrix multiplication in R using TensorFlow

Tags: r, matrix, tensorflow

A simple question.

Suppose I have an `m x m` `matrix` (`mat`)  which I'd like to raise to the power of `n`, meaning `mat %*% mat %*% mat %*%` ... (and suppose I'd like to keep all the intermediate products)

To to this using `tensorflow` (since I want to make it efficient using `GPU`s), would the `code` be:

```
library(tensorflow)
set.seed(1)
m <- 9 #in my real data m is pretty big though
mat <- matrix(rnorm(m*m),m,m)
tf.mat <- tf$constant(mat)
tf.prod.mat <- tf$constant(mat)
n <- 4
prod.list <- vector(mode="list",n)
for(i in 1:n){
  mat.mat.prod <- tf$matmul(tf.prod.mat,tf.mat)
  sess <- tf$Session()
  prod.list[[i]] <- sess$run(mat.mat.prod)
  tf.prod.mat <- tf$constant(prod.list[[i]])
}
sess$close()
```

Or am I not using `tensorflow` appropriately?

Comment: If your question is about speed, the answer is to benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `expm` library?

```
> library(expm)
> mat %^% 2  # raise to power of 2
```

Comment: The dimensions of the real data I'm dealing are very large therefore I'd like it to run on `GPU`s hence the reason for using `tensorflow`

Comment: Have you tried `gpuR` package? If you set your matrix up as GPU object it should direct commands from other packages (e.g. `expm`) to the GPU. But now I'm curious too to see if it can be done within tensorflow :)

Comment: I think that using `R`'s `tensorflow` might be simpler